# Action ActionValidateOrder didn't fired after validation

Tags: hook, prestashop

I would like to send order informations to a webservice using Curl in prestashop, the sent was successifuly with customer creation, i tried to work with hookActimonValidateOrder in my module,

I like to test the sent by the browser console and see the response but i get an empty response.
I would like to know in which prestashop page the action is executed, after clicking order confirmation in payment module page?

this is my code.

```
public function hookActionValidateOrder($params){

$adresses= $params['customer']->getAddresses($params['customer']->id_lang);
$i=0;
foreach ($adresses as $row){

 $info[$i]['country']=$row['country'];
 $info[$i]['state']=$row['state'];
 $info[$i]['city']=$row['city'];
 $info[$i]['adress1']= $row['adress1'];
 $info[$i]['adress2']= $row['adress2'];
 $info[$i]['firstname']= $row['firstname'];
 $info[$i]['postcode']= $row['postcode'];
 $i++;
}
$ch ='';
foreach($params['order']->getProducts() as $k=> $product){
 $json =$this->get("https://api.fortnox.se/3/articles/".$product['product_id']);
 $json = json_decode($json, true);
//echo $json;
 if(isset($json['ErrorInformation'])){// produit inexistant

  $resu=  $this->post("https://api.fortnox.se/3/articles/",
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Article>

  <ArticleNumber>'.$product['product_id'].'</ArticleNumber>

  <Bulky>false</Bulky>

  <ConstructionAccount></ConstructionAccount>

  <Depth>0</Depth>

  <Description>'.$product['product_name'].'</Description>

  <EAN>'.$product['product_reference'].'</EAN>

  <EUAccount></EUAccount>

  <EUVatAccount></EUVatAccount>

  <ExportAccount></ExportAccount>

  <Height>0</Height>

  <Housework>false</Housework>

  <Manufacturer></Manufacturer>

  <ManufacturerArticleNumber>'.$product['product_id'].'</ManufacturerArticleNumber>

  <Note></Note>

  <PurchaseAccount></PurchaseAccount>

  <PurchasePrice>'.$product['product_price'].'</PurchasePrice>

  <QuantityInStock>1</QuantityInStock>

  <SaleAccount>3041</SaleAccount>

  <StockGoods>false</StockGoods>

  <StockPlace>A152</StockPlace>   

  <StockWarning>0</StockWarning>

  <SupplierName></SupplierName>

  <SupplierNumber></SupplierNumber>

  <Type>0</Type>

  <Unit>St</Unit>

  <VAT>25</VAT>

  <Weight></Weight>

  <Width>0</Width>

  </Article>');
 print_r($resu);
}
    $ch.='<OrderRow>
        <AccountNumber>3011</AccountNumber>
        <ArticleNumber>'.$product['product_id'].'</ArticleNumber>
        <ContributionPercent></ContributionPercent>
        <ContributionValue></ContributionValue>
        <CostCenter></CostCenter>
        <DeliveredQuantity>'.$product['product_quantity'].'</DeliveredQuantity>
        <Description>'.$product['product_name'].'</Description>
        <Discount>'.$product['reduction_percent'].'</Discount>
        <DiscountType>PERCENT</DiscountType>
        <HouseWork>false</HouseWork>
        <OrderedQuantity>'.$product['product_quantity'].'</OrderedQuantity>
        <Price>'.$product['product_price'].'</Price>
        <Project>0</Project>
        <Total>'.$product['product_quantity']*$product['product_price'].'</Total>
        <Unit>st</Unit>
        <VAT>0</VAT>
    </OrderRow>';
}  



print_r($this->post("https://api.fortnox.se/3/orders",
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order>
<AdministrationFee>0</AdministrationFee>
<Address1>'.$info[0]['adress1'].'</Address1>
<Address2>'.$info[0]['adress2'].'</Address2>
<BasisTaxReduction></BasisTaxReduction>
<Cancelled></Cancelled>
<City>'.$info[0]['city'].'</City>
<Comments></Comments>
<ContributionPercent></ContributionPercent>
<ContributionValue></ContributionValue>
<CopyRemarks>true</CopyRemarks>
<Country>'.$info[0]['country'].'</Country>
<CostCenter></CostCenter>
<Currency>'.$params['currency']->iso_code.'</Currency>
<CurrencyRate>1</CurrencyRate>
<CurrencyUnit>1</CurrencyUnit>
<CustomerName>'.$params['customer']->firstname.' '.$params['customer']_>lastname.'</CustomerName>
<CustomerNumber>'.$params['customer']->id.'</CustomerNumber>
<DeliveryAddress1>'.$info[0]['adress1'].'</DeliveryAddress1>
<DeliveryAddress2>'.$info[0]['adress2'].'</DeliveryAddress2>
<DeliveryCity>'.$info[0]['city'].'</DeliveryCity>
<DeliveryCountry>'.$info[0]['country'].'</DeliveryCountry>
<DeliveryDate></DeliveryDate>
<DeliveryName></DeliveryName>
<DeliveryZipCode>'.$info[0]['postcode'].'</DeliveryZipCode>
<DocumentNumber></DocumentNumber>
<EmailInformation>
    <EmailAddressTo>'.$params['customer']->email.'</EmailAddressTo>
    <EmailAddressCC></EmailAddressCC>
    <EmailAddressBCC></EmailAddressBCC>
    <EmailSubject>Order {no} frهn Demobolaget</EmailSubject>
    <EmailBody>Bifogat ser ni er order.</EmailBody>
</EmailInformation>
<Freight>1</Freight>
<Gross></Gross>
<HouseWork>false</HouseWork>
<InvoiceReference></InvoiceReference>
<Language>se</Language>
<Net></Net>
<NotCompleted>false</NotCompleted>
<OfferReference></OfferReference>
<OrderDate>'.date("Y-m-d").'</OrderDate>
<OrderRows>'.$ch.
'</OrderRows>
<OrganisationNumber></OrganisationNumber>
<OurReference>O1</OurReference>
<Phone1>0470-785000</Phone1>
<Phone2>0470-785001</Phone2>
<PriceList>A</PriceList>
<PrintTemplate>ps</PrintTemplate>
<Project></Project>
<Remarks></Remarks>
<RoundOff></RoundOff>
<Sent></Sent>
<TaxReduction></TaxReduction>
<TermsOfDeliveryCode>FVL</TermsOfDeliveryCode>
<TermsOfPaymentCode>15</TermsOfPaymentCode>
<Total>'.$params['order']->total_paid.'</Total>
<TotalVat></TotalVat>
<TransactionId1></TransactionId1>
<TransactionId2>456</TransactionId2>
<VatIncluded>true</VatIncluded>
<WayOfDeliveryCode>P</WayOfDeliveryCode>
<YourReference>Pelle</YourReference>
<YourOrderNumber></YourOrderNumber>
<ZipCode></ZipCode>
</Order>
'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is executed when the customer confirms (creates, finalizes) his order in final checkout step. If you're still unsure you may always check it by doing:

1. Going to `Hook.php` class file
2. Finding `exec()` method
3. writing `error_log($hook_name);` in the method

This way when you do certain action you will be in your error log which hooks have been executed.

Secondly, you should always check if your hook ir registered - you shoudl register it during installation in `install()` method; If for some reason it still doesnt work, go to your Db, find the hook name in `hook` table, copy its ID and check if it exists in `hook_modules` table.

Also you should place some simple echo statement inside you function instead of using foreach loop - what if the array is empty for some reason (or array key doesnt exist) ?

Comment: Installed hooks are also in Design / Positions + Display non-positionable hooks enabled.